# warning STL4016: std::shared_ptr::unique() is deprecated in C++17, how to replace it?

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following usage of `.unique()`

```
void pixmappool::flush() {
  auto it = _pool.begin();

  while (it != _pool.end()) {
    if (it->second.unique()) {
      it = _pool.erase(it);
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }
}
```

Where `_pool` is: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<pixmap>, std::hash<std::string>> _pool;`

Which works very well because my application don't have threads (I do not create any).

Is it possible to change it to a "std::weak_ptr" and have the same behavior (When it has only a single copy on `_pool`, remove it).

So far what I have read, I should use `weak_ptr.lock()` to get a copy into a std::shared_ptr, and then use `weak_ptr.use_count()`, is that right?

Comment: `.use_count() == 1` is equivalent to what `.unique()` used to do. If you only have one thread, it's fine. *Or* use `std::weak_ptr`. Those two options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: You can just use `use_count` on `weak_ptr` directly, no need to `lock` (although then you should just use `expired`). The only difference to your approach is when the destructor is called; With your approach it'd be whenever the pool is the last remaining owner and you `flush`, with `weak_ptr` it'd be immediately whenever the last remaining owner releases it. Really depends on your use case which one is preferable.

Comment: "deprecated" means **only** that it **might** be removed in a future version of the standard. Until that happens, **if** it does, there's no reason to rewrite working code. And even then, library providers will continue to support it so that code that uses it won't suddenly break.